# Restrict `UpdateView` dataset for authenticated user in Class Based Views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have a Django project where I extended the User to have a Profile using a OneToOneField. I'm using CBV UpdateView which allows users to update their profile. The URL they visit for this is ../profile/***user***/update. The issue I have is that if a user types in another users name they can edit the other persons profile. How can I restrict the UpdateView so the authenticated user can only update their profile. I was trying to do something to make sure user.get_username == profile.user but having no luck.

Models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

class Profile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    SYSTEM_CHOICES = (
        ('Xbox', 'Xbox'),
        ('PS4', 'PS4'),
    )
    system = models.CharField(max_length=5,
                                    choices=SYSTEM_CHOICES,
                                      default='Xbox')
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=50)
    gamertag = models.CharField("Gamertag", max_length=50, blank=True)
    f_name = models.CharField("First Name", max_length=50, blank=True)
    l_name = models.CharField("Last Name", max_length=50, blank=True)
    twitter = models.CharField("Twitter Handle", max_length=50, blank=True)
    video = models.CharField("YouTube URL", max_length=50, default='JhBAc6DYiys', help_text="Only the extension!", blank=True)
    mugshot = models.ImageField(upload_to='mugshot', blank=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
            return u'%s' % (self.user)

    def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            Profile.objects.create(user=instance, slug=instance)

    post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('profile-detail', kwargs={'slug': self.slug})
```

Views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import DetailView
from django.views.generic.edit import UpdateView
from django.views.generic.list import ListView

from profiles.models import Profile


class ProfileDetail(DetailView):

    model = Profile

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileDetail, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

class ProfileList(ListView):
    model = Profile
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()[:3]

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileList, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context

class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Profile
    fields = ['gamertag', 'system', 'f_name', 'l_name', 'twitter', 'video', 'mugshot']
    template_name_suffix = '_update'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileUpdate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

Admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from models import Profile

class ProfileAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('user',), }

admin.site.register(Profile, ProfileAdmin)
```

Urls.py for Profiles app

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from profiles.views import ProfileDetail, ProfileUpdate

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/$', login_required(ProfileDetail.as_view()), name='profile-detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-_\w]+)/update/$', login_required(ProfileUpdate.as_view()), name='profile-update'),
)
```

Profile_update.html

```
{% extends "base.html" %} {% load bootstrap %}

{% block content %}

{% if user.is_authenticated %}

  <h1>Update your profile</h1>

  <div class="col-sm-4 col-sm-offset-4">
    <div class="alert alert-info alert-dismissible" role="alert">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
      </button>
      <strong>Heads up!</strong> Other users can find you easier if you have a completed profile.
    </div>
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="">{% csrf_token %}
      {{ form|bootstrap }}
      <input class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="Update" />
    </form>
  </div>


{% else %}
<h1>You can't update someone elses profile.</h1>
{% endif %}

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How about something like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.views import redirect_to_login


class ProfileUpdate(UpdateView):
    [...]

    def user_passes_test(self, request):
        if request.user.is_authenticated():
            self.object = self.get_object()
            return self.object.user == request.user
        return False

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.user_passes_test(request):
            return redirect_to_login(request.get_full_path())
        return super(ProfileUpdate, self).dispatch(
            request, *args, **kwargs)
```

In this example, the user is redirected to default LOGIN_URL. But you can easily change it . to redirect user to their own profile.

Comment: You, sir, are amazing.

Answer (score 3):

To avoid access to data unrelated to the connected user when using *Class Based View* (CBV), you can use *Dynamic filtering* and define `queryset` instead on `model` attributes.

If you have a `book.models` with a `ForeignKey` (named `user` here) on `auth.models.user` you can easily restrict acces like this :

```
# views.py
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin
from django.views.generic import ListView
from books.models import Book

class BookList(LoginRequiredMixin, ListView):

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Book.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
```

See more explanation in the documentation about [CBV - Viewing subsets of objects](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#dynamic-filtering)

> Specifying `model = Publisher` is really just shorthand for saying `queryset = Publisher.objects.all()`. However, by using queryset to define a filtered list of objects you can be more specific about the objects that will be visible in the view.
>
> […]
>
> Handily, the `ListView` has a `get_queryset()` method we can override. Previously, it has just been returning the value of the queryset attribute, but now we can add more logic.
>   The key part to making this work is that when class-based views are called, various useful things are stored on `self`; as well as the request (`self.request`) this includes the positional (`self.args`) and name-based (`self.kwargs`) arguments captured according to the URLconf.

Comment: You can simply this slightly by returning `super().get_queryset().filter(user=self.request.user)`. You can be agnostic about the model being used, even use this as a mixin if all the models you're using it on have their user field named `user`.

Answer (score 1):

- your template.html:

---

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated and profile.user == request.user %}
your form
{% else %}
u cannot edit that profile - its not yours...
{% endif %}
```