# how to get request.user in UpdateView django

Tags: django, django-views, django-class-based-views

I want to restrict the updateview to specefic user.How do I know which user requested the update view.I am new to django.Thanks in advance

Comment: i found the answer.if it helps others...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28800915/django-restrict-updateview-for-specific-user?rq=1

Comment: Good that you found answer, I suggest you to delete the question to avoid marking it as duplicate

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can override [**`dispatch`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin) method of UpdateView

```
class ExampleUpdate(UpdateView):

    model = Example
    form_class = ExampleUpdateForm
    template_name = 'path/to/example.html'

    def dispatch(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        # here you can make your custom validation for any particular user
        if not request.user.is_superuser:
            raise PermissionDenied()
        return super().dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

---

Or you can also use [**`PermissionRequiredMixin`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permissionrequiredmixin-mixin)

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import PermissionRequiredMixin

class MyView(PermissionRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    permission_required = 'aoo_name.can_update'
```

This mixin, just like the `permission_required` decorator, checks whether the user accessing a view has all given permissions. You should specify the permission (or an iterable of permissions) using the `permission_required` parameter

> To set user specific permissions you can read: 
>   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization